# Streamreader read next line if empty row

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem when i want to use streamreader readline by line my text file. The streamreader i using is by taking the substring, but when it comes to empty rows it pop up this error message "Index and length must refer to a location within the string". It is not exactly empty row or line, but it contains this thing "ÐôÐ#(ôd". How to skip or ignore or delete the row that not have appropriate line in text file?This is my code

```
 For Each finalname In filenames
        row2 = 1
        Using reader As New StreamReader(finalname)

            Do Until reader.EndOfStream

                Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine

                Dim datetimestring As String = line.Substring(0, 22)
                datetimestring = datetimestring.Replace("""", "").Trim()
                datetimestring = datetimestring.Replace("-", "").Trim()


                Dim format As String = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
                Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(datetimestring)
                Dim Dt = time.ToString(format)
                'Dim dtime As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(Dt)

                Dim c As String = line.Substring(22)
                c = c.Replace("-", "").Trim()

                Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("insert into table5([time] , [process], [oven], [line]) values ( @line , @line1, '" & oven & "', '" & row2 & "')", con1)
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@line", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = time
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@line1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = c
                con1.Open()
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con1.Close()
                row2 = row2 + 1

            Loop
            oven = oven + 2
            Dim str20 As String = "data source=10.239.213.40;uid=sa;pwd=Win32API;database=mbi"
            Dim con20 As New SqlConnection(str20)
            Dim com20 As String = "select top 9 * from table5 where process like '%Load lot clicked%' or process like '%''QCheck'' Button%' or process like '%''Start'' Button%' or process like '%Run Proc%' or process like '%Run Bin2 clicked%' or process like '%Started with Double click%' and oven ='2' order by oven, line desc"
            Dim Adpt20 As New SqlDataAdapter(com20, con1)
            Dim ds2 As New DataSet()
            Adpt20.Fill(ds2, "table5")
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds2.Tables(0)

        End Using

    Next
```

Comment: Since you are hard-coding an index position inside a string, you should then check beforehand that the string contains, at least, that number of chars. You could insert: `If line.Length < 22 Then Continue Do` right after `reader.ReadLine`.

Comment: @Jimi it working

Comment: Then pick one of the answers, because this is what they are suggesting you could do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine
 If(String.ISNullorWhiteSpace(line) = false Then
Dim datetimestring As String = line.Substring(0, 22)
                datetimestring = datetimestring.Replace("""", "").Trim()
                datetimestring = datetimestring.Replace("-", "").Trim()


                Dim format As String = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
                Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(datetimestring)
                Dim Dt = time.ToString(format)
                'Dim dtime As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(Dt)

                Dim c As String = line.Substring(22)
                c = c.Replace("-", "").Trim()

                Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("insert into table5([time] , [process], [oven], [line]) values ( @line , @line1, '" & oven & "', '" & row2 & "')", con1)
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@line", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = time
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@line1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = c
                con1.Open()
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con1.Close()
                row2 = row2 + 1
End If
```

If line.Substring is the issue then check with something like this

```
Dim lineLength As Int = line.Length()
Dim datetimestring As String   =If(line.Substring(0, 22) = Null, "", ine.Substring(0, 22))

Dim datetimestring As String   =If(lineLength < 22, "", line.Substring(0, 22))
```

Comment: I updated the answer, if it is a sub string of line then you have to make sure what you want is there

Comment: I want it delete the row that have this "äôä7ôd". Already try using your code still not working

Comment: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use SubString function, as you noted when a line is shorter than 22 characters the program will crash.
Typically I will subdivide or split the line into different parts by using Split function, for example:

```
 dim ast() as string = line.split("XXX")
```

then extract the specific string from it:

```
datetimestring = ast(0)
```

this, of course, requires the parts are seperated by common delimiters, such as ',' or empty spaces, etc.

Also, add additional condition after reading the line, for example:

```
Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine
If String.ISNullorWhiteSpace(line) orelse line.length < 10  Then continue do
```

Comment: it's hard for me to use split, because they only have two column from text file which is time and process. I can divide time and process using "-" split. But in the process details contains also "-". Plus what i want is either delete the empty row, or skip that line.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do Until reader.EndOfStream
Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine
If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) AndAlso Not line.Length < 22 Then

'put the rest of your do-loop code here

End If
Loop
```